# Good guide about Ruby classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am php developer and I'm trying to change php to ruby/rails.

I've read "Rails for PHP developers" by Pargmatic, but it is very simple.

Now I need to learn all about ruby classes (namespacing, abstraction, extending, factory/signleton patterns, requesting parent class methods, etc), but all guides and manuals I've seen was to simple, they was good only for beginners as a introduction.

Reading Ruby reference isn't good idea, because it's to difficult for understanding (my skills in ruby are not so good yet), so I need some guide for "professional developers" with many examples. Good example is "php|architect's Zend PHP 5 Certification Study Guide" - [http://www.amazon.com/architects-Zend-Certification-Study-Guide/dp/0973862149](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0973862149)

Are there any book/guide/course to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: pragprog has other excellent books on rails and ruby. Check them out.

Comment: This question is not very appropriate for Stack Overflow, I'm sorry to say. There is no definitive answer which everyone can say "Yes, hard facts and a clear fitness criteria prove that this answer solves the question." What you're asking for is subjective.

Comment: THE definitive resource is the The Ruby Programming Language by Flanagan and Matsumoto by O'Reilly.  You will certainly find that technical enough.  OiReilly also have Ruby Best Practices which can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the book from the master (aka Ruby creator) himself: [http://www.amazon.com/Ruby-Programming-Language-David-Flanagan/dp/0596516177](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177)

You need this.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Matz is the co-author; what's the issue?

Comment: Easy there Dave, you'll notice that he's referring to the "Ruby creator".  I know that David and Matz wrote the book together but I thought that Matz himself was the Ruby creator.  Please correct me if I'm wrong though, always open to learn more.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Not sure I can take it any easier--don't take disagreement for being upset. Matz *is* the Ruby creator, so the book is by him, and David.

Comment: No problem I just see "aka Ruby creator" for David and think, hmmm, that's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

"Metaprogramming Ruby" is well worth adding to your bookshelf.
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Metaprogramming-Ruby-Program-Like-Facets/dp/1934356476/

Comment: Sure, but hardly appropriate for something that doesn't know Ruby, like the OP.

Comment: except they asked specifically for non-beginners material, as they understand the OO principles, and want to see them used in Ruby. Moot though, as the question is closed now.